# Error 405 cuando xmlhttpRequest realiza un post sobre una carpeta de servidor

Tags: .net, http, iis

Me gustaría usar un código para cargar varios archivos al servidor. Mi servidor es un IIS 8.5 y he sondeado estas herramientas:

http://fineuploader.com/

y

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

El problema es que ambos, me devuelven un error 405 cuando se ejecuta XMLHTTPRequest sobre  carpeta de destino.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Estas probando guardar los archivos que subes en una carpeta local de tu ordenador?

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede deberse a:

1.- No estas especificando correctamente la ruta, incluye una ruta absoluta si es posible tipo http://www.midominio.es/almacen/fichero

2.- La carpeta no tiene permisos o el método de ejecución (GET,POST, PUT, etc...) no esta permitido.

En cualquier caso, ¿Nos podrías enseñar como tienes el código de la llamada?

Answer (score 0):

El error 405 proviene de intentar usar un mètodo HTTP 'X' sobre un recurso que no lo soporta. Por ejemplo, hacer un POST a una URL a la que sòlo se le puede hacer GET.

Por lo tanto, la URL evidentemente existe, pero el mètodo HTTP no es soportado. Si la URL no existiese, te devolverìa un error 404.
Vas a tener que publicar algo de còdigo o nadie te va  apoder ayudar de manera sustancial.

Comment: Para hacer una prueba de concepto, directamente he utilizado el código que proponen.

Comment: http://fineuploader.com/demos.html

Comment: Perdón por ponerlo en varios mensajes. He creado un aplicación vacía, sólo con el código de ejemplo que proponen. Me carga la página para seleccionar el fichero de manera correcta. En la configuración de fineuploader hay que indicar la carpeta donde se guardaran los ficheros:

Comment: var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
            template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
            request: {
                endpoint: 'temp/'
            },
 thumbnails: {
 placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
 }
 },
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true,
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials:true
        });

Comment: Probé a modificar el Handler Mapping de static file en IIS poniendo escritura en vez de lectura, pero creo que no van por ahí los tiros. Así conseguí que me diera un 403, pero he dado permisos de escritura al usuario y sigue sin funcionar.

Un saludo